# What's the nth integral of $\frac1{x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

It can be shown by simple induction that $\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\left(\dfrac1{x}\right) =  \dfrac{(-1)^n n!}{x^{n+1}}$.

But what about the nth integral of $\dfrac1{x}$? Finding the first few primitives, I can't discern a pattern.

Comment: The nth integral appears to be $\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\log x-(\text{something})\cdot x^{n-1}$, but I can't quite discern the (something) yet.

Comment: The specific sequence of powers you get by repeatedly antidifferentiating in the way that I expect Isaac is doing is interesting.  When written in lowest terms, the numerator of the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is the numerator of the $(n-1)$th Harmonic number (the $k$th Harmonic number is $H_k = \sum_{j=1}^k 1/j$).  The sequence of denominators you get is not in the OEIS.

Comment: You need to pick a lower bound or else "the integral" is only well-defined up to a constant, so the nth integral will only be well-defined up to a polynomial of degree n-1.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As Isaac noted, repeated integration seems to give the following pattern

$$ \frac{x^{n-1} \log x}{(n-1)!} - C_n x^{n-1}$$

Note that the value of $\displaystyle C_n$ does not really matter, as differentiating $n$ times nukes it. Also, note that, we can add any arbitrary $\displaystyle (n-1)^{th}$ degree polynomial to this, without changing the $\displaystyle n^{th}$ derivative.

In order to prove that the $\displaystyle n^{th}$ derivative of $\displaystyle  \frac{x^{n-1} \log x}{(n-1)!}$ is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}$, we can use induction.

$$ \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{d (x^{n-1} \log x)}{dx} = \frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{x^{n-2} \log x}{(n-2)!}$$

Since adding an arbitrary $\displaystyle (n-2)^{th}$ degree polynomial does not change the $\displaystyle (n-1)^{th}$ derivative of $\displaystyle \frac{x^{n-2} \log x}{(n-2)!}$ we are done using induction.

Note that if $\displaystyle f(x)$ is another function such that $\displaystyle \frac{d^n f}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$, then we have that $\displaystyle \phi(x) = f(x) - \frac{x^{n-1} \log x}{(n-1)!}$ has it's $\displaystyle n^{th}$ derivative to be zero, and hence it is a polynomial of degree $\displaystyle n-1$ or lower (can be proved using induction, again).

Thus all the functions you are looking for are of the form

$$\frac{x^{n-1} \log x}{(n-1)!} + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} c_j x^j$$

where $\displaystyle c_j$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: That means the nth integral of $1/x$ is $\frac{x^{n-1}\log x}{(n-1)!}+$ an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n-1$ or less.

Comment: @TCL: Yes, although the answer does not explicitly claim that these are the only functions, it can be modified to do that, I suppose.

Comment: @TCL: I have modified the answer with a proof sketch of that being all possible functions.

Answer (score 20):

If we use the [repeated integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RepeatedIntegral.html) formula on the reciprocal function, with $1$ as the lower limit, we get

$$\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\int_1^x\int_1^{t_{n-1}}\cdots\int_1^{t_1}}_{n} \frac1{t}\;\mathrm dt\cdots\mathrm dt_{n-2}\mathrm dt_{n-1}&=\frac1{(n-1)!}\int_1^x\frac{(x-t)^{n-1}}{t}\mathrm dt\\
&=(-1)^n \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}B_{1-x}(n,1-n)
\end{align*}$$

where $B_x(a,b)$ is the [incomplete beta function](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/).

Letting

$$g_n(x)=(-1)^n \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}B_{1-x}(n,1-n)$$

the following more "elementary" representation can be derived:

$$g_n(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}(\ln\,x-H_{n-1})-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^j}{j\cdot j!}\frac{x^{n-j-1}}{(n-j-1)!}$$

where $H_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\frac1{j}$ is a harmonic number.

As Aryabhata mentions in his answer,

$$\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\left(\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\ln\;x+p_{n-1}(x)\right)=\frac1{x}$$

where $p_{n-1}(x)$ is any polynomial of degree $n-1$; $g_n(x)$, however, has the special property (by virtue of how it was constructed) that

$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dx^k}g_n(x)\right|_{x=1}=0\quad \text{if}\quad k < n$$

Comment: Actually, it does not really matter what the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is , as adding an arbitrary $(n-1)^{th}$ degree polynomial won't change the derivative.

Comment: @Mo: True, that.

Comment: ...and indulge me a little sidebar: the "repeated integral" formula generalizes to arbitrary *complex* values of $n$ (i.e. it's the Riemann-Liouville differintegral), but I had already done some simplification under the assumption that $n$ is an integer.

Comment: Thank you... makes me want to smack myself for not being familiar with special functions.

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this problem by the use of fractional derivatives.

$\forall q < 0$, using the [Riemann Liouville formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral) and substituting $v = \frac{x-y}{x}$:

$$
\frac{d^q}{dx^q}\log x = \\
\frac{1}{\Gamma(-q)} \int_0^x \frac{\log (y)}{(x-y)^{q+1}}\, dy=\\
\frac{x^{-q} \log x}{\Gamma(-q)}\int_0^1 \frac{dv}{v^{q+1}} + \frac{x^{-q}}{\Gamma(-q)}\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-v)}{v^{q+1}}\, dv
$$

The first integral equals $-\frac{1}{q}$, while the second one is evaluated by parts:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-v)}{v^{q+1}}\, dv = \\
\frac{1}{q} \int_0^1 \log(1-v)\,d(1-v^{-q}) = \\
\frac{\log(1-v^{-q}) \log(1-v)}{q}\big|_0^1 - \frac{1}{q} \int_0^1 \frac{1-v^{-q}}{1-v}\, dv = \\
\frac{\psi(1-q)+\gamma}{q}
$$

Then

$$\frac{d^q}{dx^q}\log x = \frac{x^{-q}}{\Gamma(1-q)}(\log x - \gamma - \psi(1-q))$$

Letting $q \mapsto -q$ and letting $q$ be an integer, and differentiating once we obtain:

$$\boxed{I^q \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x^{q-1}}{q!}\left(q\log x + q\sum_{n=1}^q \frac{1}{n}+1\right)+P_{n-1}(x)}$$

where $I^q$ represents the $q^{th}$ integral and $P_{n-1} (x)$ represents a polynomial of degree $n-1$.  Note that the sum above is for the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Reference: The Fractional Calculus (Oldham & Spanier)

Answer (score 3):

After replacing the variable x with t, the first step is to start the iterative integration at the log(t) rather than 1/t. The nth antiderivative of the natural logarithm is given by the following.

If 
$
n\geq 0\in \mathbb{Z}\land t>0\in \mathbb{R}
$
then,
$$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-n)}(t)=\frac{t^n}{(n!)^2}(n! \log (t)+\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)})
$$

**Proof**, by induction on n.

**Proposition at n:**

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-n)}(t)=\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)} t^n}{(n!)^2}+\frac{t^n \log (t)}{n!}
$

**Proposition at n=0:**

The Stirling number of the first kind term evaluates to zero,
$
S_1^{(2)}=0
$
.

Substitute and simplify.

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(0)}(t)=0+\frac{t^0 \log (t)}{0!}=\log (t)
$

**Proposition at n+1:**
Integrate the proposition at n with suitable antiderivative limits.

$$
\displaystyle \int_0^t \log ^{(-n)}(u) \, du=\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)}}{(n!)^2}\int_0^t u^n \, du+\frac{1}{n!}\int _0^tu^n \log (u)du 
$$

Evaluate the first integral.

$
\int_0^t \log ^{(-n)}(u) \, du=\log ^{(-(n+1))}(t)-\log ^{(-(n+1))}(0)
$

If n>0, then the following is true.

$
\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0} \, \log ^{(-n)}(t)=\log ^{(-n)}(0)
$

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-n)}(0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \, \left(\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)} t^n}{(n!)^2}+\frac{t^n \log (t)}{n!}\right)
$

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-n)}(0)=\lim_{t\to 0} \, \frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)} t^n}{(n!)^2}+\lim_{t\to 0} \, \frac{t^n \log (t)}{n!}
$

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-n)}(0)=0+0
$

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-(n+1))}(0)=0
$

Substituting,

$
\displaystyle \int_0^t \log ^{(-n)}(u) \, du=\log ^{(-(n+1))}(t)
$

Evaluate the second integral.

$
\displaystyle \frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)}}{(n!)^2}\int_0^t u^n \, du=\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)}}{(n!)^2} \frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)}
$

Evaluate the third integral.

$
\displaystyle \frac{1}{n!}\int _0^tu^n \log (u)du=-\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2 n!}+\frac{t^{n+1} \log (t)}{(n+1)!}
$

Assemble the proposition at n+1 equation.

$
\displaystyle \log ^{(-(n+1))}(t)=\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)}}{(n!)^2} \frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)}-\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2 n!}+\frac{t^{n+1} \log (t)}{(n+1)!}
$

Now the strategy is to show that the following is true.

$
\displaystyle \frac{\cos ((n+1)\pi ) S_{n+2}^{(2)} t^{n+1}}{((n+1)!)^2}=\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)}}{(n!)^2} \frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)}-\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2 n!}
$

Simplify the preceding equation.

$
\displaystyle \frac{\cos ((n+1)\pi ) S_{n+2}^{(2)} t^{n+1}}{((n+1)!)^2}=\frac{\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)}}{(n!)^2} \frac{(n+1) t^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{n! t^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2 (n!)^2}
$

$
\displaystyle -\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+2}^{(2)}=\cos (n \pi ) S_{n+1}^{(2)} (n+1)-n!
$

$
\displaystyle n! \cos (n \pi )= (n+1) S_{n+1}^{(2)}+S_{n+2}^{(2)}
$

Utilize the following identities from the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions.

- [(1)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8.E14) $ \displaystyle \quad S_n^{(1)}=(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!$
- [(2)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8.E18) $ \displaystyle \quad S_n^{(k)}=S_{n-1}^{(k-1)}-(n-1) S_{n-1}^{(k)}$

Shift and apply the first identity.

$
\displaystyle n=n+1
$

$
\displaystyle S_{n+1}^{(1)}=n! \cos (n \pi )
$

$
\displaystyle S_{n+1}^{(1)}=(n+1) S_{n+1}^{(2)}+S_{n+2}^{(2)}
$

Shift, rearrange, and compare the second identity..

$
\displaystyle n=n+2
$

$
\displaystyle S_{n+2}^{(k)}=S_{n+1}^{(k-1)}-(n+1) S_{n+1}^{(k)}
$

$
\displaystyle S_{n+1}^{(k-1)}=(n+1) S_{n+1}^{(k)}+S_{n+2}^{(k)}
$

The proposition at n+1 is equivalent to the preceding identity with the variable k=2. Therefore, the proposition at n+1 is true.
$
\displaystyle \Box
$

Quite possibly for the first time in human history, we are now able to gaze upon the googolplexth antiderivative of the natural logarithm:)

$$
\displaystyle \frac{t^{10^{10^{100}}}}{\left(10^{10^{100}}!\right)^2} \left(10^{10^{100}}! \log (t)+S_{10^{10^{100}}+1}^{(2)} \cos \left(\pi  10^{10^{100}}\right)\right)+C
$$

**History:**
It's odd! I must have looked at this problem a zillion times before and never saw it. But this time the solution just fell out. I generated the following repeated integration table.

$
t^k \log (t)\\ \frac{t^{k+1} \log (t)}{k+1}-\frac{t^{k+1}}{(k+1)^2}\\ \frac{t^{k+2} \log (t)}{k^2+3 k+2}-\frac{(2 k+3) t^{k+2}}{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2}\\ \frac{t^{k+3} \log (t)}{k^3+6 k^2+11 k+6}-\frac{\left(3 k^2+12 k+11\right) t^{k+3}}{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2 (k+3)^2}\\ \frac{t^{k+4} \log (t)}{(k+1) (k+2) (k+3) (k+4)}-\frac{2 \left(2 k^3+15 k^2+35 k+25\right) t^{k+4}}{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2 (k+3)^2 (k+4)^2}\\ \frac{t^{k+5} \log (t)}{(k+1) (k+2) (k+3) (k+4) (k+5)}-\frac{\left(5 k^4+60 k^3+255 k^2+450 k+274\right) t^{k+5}}{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2 (k+3)^2 (k+4)^2 (k+5)^2}\\ \frac{t^{k+6} \log (t)}{(k+1) (k+2) (k+3) (k+4) (k+5) (k+6)}-\frac{\left(6 k^5+105 k^4+700 k^3+2205 k^2+3248 k+1764\right) t^{k+6}}{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2 (k+3)^2 (k+4)^2 (k+5)^2 (k+6)^2}\\ \frac{t^{k+7} \log (t)}{(k+1) (k+2) (k+3) (k+4) (k+5) (k+6) (k+7)}-\frac{\left(7 k^6+168 k^5+1610 k^4+7840 k^3+20307 k^2+26264 k+13068\right) t^{k+7}}{(k+1)^2 (k+2)^2 (k+3)^2 (k+4)^2 (k+5)^2 (k+6)^2 (k+7)^2}
$

I wondered if the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences had any information on the following.
$
\displaystyle \{7,168,1610,7840,20307,26264,13068\}
$

At oeis.org/A196837 I found a formula for a Stirling Triangle. It was all downhill form there. I figured out a formula for the constant coefficient terms and let k goto zero.

In conclusion, here is a table of the first seven antiderivatives of the natural logarithm.
$
\displaystyle \begin{array}{ll}
 \text{n} & \text{antiderivative} \\
\hline
 0 & \log (t) \\
 1 & t (\log (t)-1) \\
 2 & t^2 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\right) \\
 3 & t^3 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{6}-\frac{11}{36}\right) \\
 4 & t^4 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{24}-\frac{25}{288}\right) \\
 5 & t^5 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{120}-\frac{137}{7200}\right) \\
 6 & t^6 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{720}-\frac{49}{14400}\right) \\
 7 & t^7 \left(\frac{\log (t)}{5040}-\frac{121}{235200}\right)
\end{array}
$

Peace

Comment: To simplify further, $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$ for integer $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that

$$\int \frac{1}{x} dx= \ln (x) + C $$  Now integrate again

**Hint :**
$\displaystyle\int \ln(x) dx = x \ln(x)-x +C$

Comment: Well, I did. I've found that $I_{1} = \ln{x}+k, ~ I_{2} = x\left(\ln{x}-1\right), ~ I_{3} = 4x^2\left(2\ln(x)-3\right)$, etc.

Comment: @user4558 I have done the same, it would be nice to find a recurrence, I believe that exist

Comment: @user4558 $I_{3}=\frac{x^2}{4}(2 \ln(x)-3)$ :)

Comment: You are right, of course. That's what I meant to write. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

The $n^{th}$ integration of $ln(x)$ from $x$ to $1$ is equal to $\frac{x^{n}}{n!}(ln(x)-H_n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{H_{n+k-1}}{(n+k-1)!}*\frac{x-1}{(k-1)!}.$

Where $H_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.

The $x-1$ terms suggest that there is a function whose value at $1$ equals $\frac{H_{n}}{n!}$, derivative at $1=\frac{H_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$, second derivative at $1=\frac{H_{n-2}}{(n-2)!}$,... ect. This is because the sum resembles the Taylor expansion at $a=1.$ Very interesting.

Comment: (a) I suggest writing your answer in LaTeX, rather than plain text, see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:About
(b) It would be helpful if you could give some context (e.g. the definition of $H(n)$, how you derive the formula, etc.

Comment: I derived the formula by doing the integrations and figuring out what the terms are. No real step 1, step 2,.. to give.

Comment: @e2theipi2026 Wow! An edit after almost 4 years!

Comment: @Irregular User  lol, I know. I haven't used the site since then. Hi I'm back! lol