# Closed form for n-th anti-derivative of $\log x$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, closed-form

Is it possible to write a closed-form expression with free variables $x, n$ representing the n-th anti-derivative of $\log x$?

Comment: http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1692-02.pdf

Comment: Basically a duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13591/27624

Comment: @Argon: Even though I cast a close vote, I now believe it is slightly different, as the $H_n$ term becomes important for $\log x$, but not for $\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$\log^{(-n)}x=\frac{x^n}{n!}(\log x-H_n),$$
where $H_n$ is the [harmonic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html): $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}=\,$[$\gamma$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html)$\,+\,$[$\psi$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)$(n+1)=\gamma+\frac{\Gamma'(n+1)}{n!}$

*Proof*: By induction.

Comment: I am not sure if it would be a proper notation if I wrote $(d/dx)^{-n}\log x=...$

Comment: Writing $\log^{(-n)}(x)$ looks a little better : [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration)

Comment: Oldham and Spanier in their "The Fractional Calculus" use $\frac{d^{-n}}{dx^{-n}}$

Comment: I think your $H_n$ is defined incorrectly.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks, it was totally wrong! I kept in mind the sum of an initial segment of the harmonic series, but for some reason wrote the divergent sum of the whole series.

Comment: You can add an arbitrary $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial...

Answer (score 6):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2), [(II)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390866/recursion-relation-for-euler-numbers/390908#390908). Here is a [unified formula](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5328945&tag=1) for the $n$th derivative and the $n$th anti-derivative of real order of $\ln(x)$ in terms of the [Meijer G function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function)

> $$ G^{1, 2}_{2, 2}\left(x-1\, \Big\vert\,^{1-n, 1-n}_{1-n, 0}\right). $$

The above formula gives

a) derivatives of real order if $n>0$,

b) anti-derivatives of real order if $n<0$.

One can have the above formula in terms of the hypergeometric formula

> $$ {\frac { \left( x-1 \right) ^{1-n}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,1;\,2-n;\,1-x)}
> }{\Gamma  \left( 2-n \right) }},$$

with some restrictions on $n$.

Comment: (+1) its so beautiful to find closed form using Meijer G function but how to prove it ?

Answer (score 6):

An intuitive way to get the formula from the answer of Vladimir Reshetnikov without induction:

Recall that $\displaystyle\ln x=\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\frac{x^s-1}{s}$. But the $n$th antiderivative of $x^s-1$ is very easy to compute:
$$\frac{1}{s}\underbrace{\int\ldots\int}_{n\;\text{times}}(x^s-1)dx=\frac{x^{s+n}}{s(s+1)\ldots(s+n)}-\frac{x^n}{s\cdot n!}=_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(\ln x-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right).$$

Comment: There is a typo, you are missing a $\frac{1}{s}$ in $\ln x = \lim\dots$. Don't you need some justification for taking the limit inside though?

Comment: @Aryabhata: Thank you! I've edited it. Of course this is not a rigorous derivation, I just tried to make the formula of V.R. less misterious, as usually the hardest part in the proof by induction is to guess the form of the answer...