# Do the turning points of the repeated integrals of ln (x) trace out a logarithmic curve with respect to the y-axis?

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, roots

[image: Graph of repeated integrals of ln(x)]

It's just something I noticed while graphing the repeated integrals (C = 0) of ln (x). I'm not exactly sure how to prove that they do trace out a logarithmic curve. I did find this post on math stackexchange which is able to find the nth integral of 1/x (or the (n-1)th integral of ln (x)), and I was thinking of using that to find the zeroes of the previous integral (which is the turning points of the next one): [What's the nth integral of $\frac1{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13591/whats-the-nth-integral-of-frac1x)
Also see: [Does the repeated integral of $\ln x$ have a pattern?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827309/does-the-repeated-integral-of-ln-x-have-a-pattern)

I hope you find it an interesting problem as I did, and maybe we can come up with something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your link, we obtain a formula for the nth integral of 1/x, so we can study what happens as n goes to infinity. We have that $lim_(n->∞)$$x^(n-1)/((n - 1)!)=0$ since generally n! is larger than a^n ([Do factorials really grow faster than exponential functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351815/do-factorials-really-grow-faster-than-exponential-functions)).

So this means that we are left with a linear combination of x, so we have $c_1$x+$c_1$x+.......=Ax where A is an infinite sum. It really depends on what this A is. If A=0 for example then we have y=0, the real axis. (Graphs of first few integrals of 1/x https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cqowlr8b9p). You can see it from your sketch that the graphs are stretching out form the origin, so if C=0, you get the positive real line.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the answer!